# Is this a correct way to use triangle inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

If I have:

$$|g_1(x) - g_2(x) - (g_1(a) - g_2(a))| \leq f(x^*)$$

Can I proceed to say:

$$|g_1(x) - g_2(x) - (g_1(a) - g_2(a))| \leq |g_1(x) - g_2(x)| - |(g_1(a) - g_2(a))|$$
$$ \implies |g_1(x) - g_2(x)| \leq |g_1(a) - g_2(a)| + f(x^*)$$

Little bit confused because, how can we say the over-estimate is still $\leq f(x^*)$

I feel as if the first line should read:

$$|g_1(x) - g_2(x) - (g_1(a) - g_2(a))| \geq |g_1(x) - g_2(x)| - |g_1(a) - g_2(a)|$$

This would make more sense, wouldn't it?

Comment: In a general case, and for the reason you pointed out, you can't. (It might still be true in a specific example, though)

Comment: Could I make the assertion I have in my final line, i.e:

$$|g_1(x) - g_2(x) - (g_1(a) - g_2(a))| \geq |g_1(x) - g_2(x)| - |g_1(a) - g_2(a)|$$ ?

Comment: This is not correct; you need to take the absolute value of the whole RHS. See [Reverse Triangle Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality).

Comment: @Demosthene: Doesn't the reverse triangle inequality imply the inequality in Steezetz's comment?

Comment: @Regret Just realized Steezetz is the OP :)

Comment: What do you mean that it's missing an absolute value to the right hand side?

Answer (score 1):

$|a-b|\ge|a|-|b|$. So your last inequality works, not the first.

Comment: Thanks, this is all I needed to know.

Is the last inequality called "reverse triangle inequality" ?

Also Demosthene seems to disagree that it holds, is there any reason for this, or is he mistaken?

Comment: Yes, it essentially follows from the triangle inequality.